# Concatenate strings from several rows - part 2

Tags: pandas

How can I group concatenate the rows from a dataframe using Pandas?

The ideea is that using that article solution:

```
 df = df(['ID','Defect Attribute'])['Defect Check'].apply('|'.join).reset_index()
```

worked great but only if I have these 3 columns.

```
ID|Defect Atribute|Defect Check|
```

My case is that the df is like this:

```
ID|...8 columns with important info|Defect Atribute|Defect Check|...38 colums with important info.

ID|Name|Number|...|Defect Atribute|Defect Check|Date      |Purchases|...
100|Abc |123  |...|Specification  |Size        |11.10.2020|3        |...
100|Abc |123  |...|Specification  |Color       |11.10.2020|3        |...
101|Bcd |345  |...|Specification  |Brand       |11.10.2020|2        |...
101|Bcd |345  |...|Specification  |Color       |11.10.2020|2        |...
```

The idea is I added the columns in between(8 attributes between ID and Defect Attribute) and it works perfectly with the method provided in the article, but when I try to add the attributes after Defect Check, it crashes.

I would like to make it like this:

```
ID|Name|Number|...|Defect Atribute|Defect Check    |Date      |Purchases|...
100|Abc |123  |...|Specification  |Size/Color/Brand|11.10.2020|3        |...
101|Bcd |345  |...|Specification  |Brnad/Color     |11.10.2020|3        |...
```

Comment: This type of operation is called a "pivot". What you want to do is pivot the table so you have: `ID|Name|...|Size|Color|Brand`, and from there you can easily glue the Size/color/brand columns into a string.

Comment: Hello @Matthew I have tried the method sugested and i get the following error msg: raise ValueError("Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"). I don't think the metod works for me.